# Painting order walls or vanity

Tags: painting

I'm remodeling my bathroom on a limited budget , I am spray painting my vanity , and also painting the walls with wall paint , which should I do first ?
Vanity or walls ?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you spraying the walls as well?

Comment: Will you be removing the vanity so you can paint behind it and so overspray from the vanity doesn't hit the walls? Are you spraying, rolling or brushing the walls?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not removing the vanity, I'd suggest spraying first, then brush/roller on the walls (with appropriate dry time of the spray paint) and masking off the vanity where it meets the wall.  Spraying will spread a lot more extra paint in the air, and by spraying first, that extra paint that might accidentally land on the walls will be nicely covered up by the wall paint.  But I would still mask off the walls before spraying as well.